# FileStatistics -- trouble counting the number of words in a file

Tags: java, file-io

In my course, we are tasked with determining three key statistics about a file that is passed via the console input: 1) number of characters, 2) number of lines, 3) number of words. Before closing this question as a duplicate, please read on to see what unique problem I'm encountering. Thank you :)

I originally wrote a solution with three separate methods and three separate Scanner variables, but I realized that for larger files, this solution would be very inefficient. Instead, I decided to write up a solution that only runs through the file a single time and calculates all three statistics in one go. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class FileStatistics
{   

    // Note: uncomment (A) and (B) below to test execution time

    public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException
    {

        /* (A)
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        */

        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        int numChars = 0, numWords = 0, numLines = 0;



        /* Calculations */

        while( input.hasNextLine() )
        {
            String currentLine = input.nextLine();
            numLines++;
            numChars+= currentLine.length();

            String [] words = currentLine.split(" ");
            numWords += words.length;               
        }
        input.close();



        /* Results */
        System.out.println( "File " + file.getName() + " has ");
        System.out.println( numChars + " characters");
        System.out.println( numWords + " words");
        System.out.println( numLines + " lines");


        /* (B) 
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Execution took: " + (endTime-startTime)/1000.0 + " seconds");
        */

    }


}
```

I've been comparing the results of my program to Microsoft Word's own file statistics by simply copy/pasting the contents of whatever file I'm using into Word. The number of characters and number of lines are calculated correctly.

However, my program does not properly count the number of words. I decided to include a test statement in there to print out the contents of the array `words`, and it seems that certain "spatial formatting" (like tabs from a Java source code file) are being treated as individual elements in the split array. I tried doing `currentLine.replace("\t", "")` before invoking the split method  to remove those tabs, but this didn't change a thing.

Could someone please offer some advice or hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Currently, `currentLine.split(" ")` only matches the space character. To match all whitespace characters, include new-line and tab, you can use the `\\s+` regex instead: `currentLine.split("\\s+")`. Maybe this will solve your issue.

Comment: Nope, still shows that I have 157 words with that revision, whereas Microsoft Word says there are 125 words. Note that I'm passing this very source code as args[0]

Comment: Can you provide the input file that you are using?

Comment: Yep, it's this source code, FileStatistics.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the String array returned by `currentLine.split(" ")` can contain elements which are empty Strings: `""`. You can see this if you call `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words))`.

To create the desired behavior, you can store `words.length` in a variable `count` and decrement `count` for each instance of the empty string `""` in `words`.

Here is a sample solution:

```
while( input.hasNextLine() )
{
    String currentLine = input.nextLine();
    numLines++;
    numChars+= currentLine.length();

    String [] words = currentLine.split("\\s+");
    int count = words.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].equals("")) {
            count--;
        }
    }
    numWords += count;
}
```

Alternatively, you can convert `words` to an `ArrayList` and use the `removeAll()` functions:

```
while( input.hasNextLine() )
{
    String currentLine = input.nextLine();
    numLines++;
    numChars+= currentLine.length();

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(currentLine.split("\\s+")));
    words.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
    numWords += words.size();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm looking for a more elegant/optimized solution that doesn't require more looping. I simply can't figure out how to get split to wok properly.

Comment: There is no significantly more elegant solution using `String.split()` because the function is defined to include empty Strings. You can check out [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter), which has better String splitting capabilities. Alternatively, you can convert `words` to an `ArrayList` and use the `removeAll()` function, but that's likely less efficient than using a loop.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a solution using `ArrayList` and `removeAll()`. Perhaps this is what you're looking for. Short of this, there are no elegant solutions using `String.split()`.